# Generate a list in M (Power Query) with a given incrementor and maximum value

Tags: powerquery, m

I am using Microsoft Power Query (M) to retrieve paginated data. I am able to get the total number of records to retrieve, and I can specify the number of records per call to return as well as the index to begin retrieval.

I need to generate a list of numbers that represent starting points for each call.

For example, I have 8,227 records to retrieve, and I can retrieve 2,000 at a time. I would like to generate a list of numbers beginning at 1 and incrementing by 2000 each time until I reach my maximum value. In this case, my list would be

```
1 2001 4001 6001 8001
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#"Step" = List.Generate(()=>1, each _ < 8227, each _ + 2000)
```